# Visual Studio 2017, 2019 and 2022 crash when opening certain form in designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I´m using MaterialSkin.2 to create a winForms application. I have a main MaterialForm that shows features, which I implemented by creating userControls. Every version of Visual Studio Community I have crashes, when I open the main form in the designer and it has a certain feature added. The feature itself doesn´t crash the designer, when I open it. It has a MaterialButton and if I remove it from the feature the designer doesn´t crash anymore.

I use a windows application packaging project. I deployed the app and it worked perfectly. Then the problem suddenly started appearing while I was working on another feature. I didn´t change anything about the feature that crashes the designer. And the app still runs when I debug it. I don´t really get errors. Visual studio just freezes and crashes after a few seconds. Sometimes I get 2 errors before it crashes:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/82h0bzkc37uj2d7/IMG_1341.png?dl=0

The 2. error is "The variable settingsTab1 has not been declared or assigned". But there is no error in the code anywhere.

I tried everything. I tried VS17, VS19 and VS22, repaired all of them, pulled a commit from 4 days ago to readd the new code line after line, I even tried to debug VS19 with VS19 because I didn´t get an error code or anything. But it just says

> Exception thrown at 0x75AED8A2 (KernelBase.dll)

I used dotnetSpy to turn my installed version into a project again and it still crashes. What am I doing wrong? and what could I try to fix my project?

Comment: Then the `settingsTab1` is the problem and that interrupts the `InitializeComponent();` business. Check it in your code and make sure that it's not `null` where it shouldn't be `null`. Where you access it at that point. Also, you could try: Open the solution and don't open the designer. Run another VS2022 instance and hit the _Continue without code_ link. Hit the _Attach_ button, select your solution from the _Available processes_ list and press _Attach_. Now, switch back to the first VS instance and open the designer. See if the 2nd instance can show you where the bug exactly is.

Comment: I will try that. I´m pretty sure it has nothing to do with `settingsTab1`. I just tried removing it completely and it still doesn´t work. And if `settingsTab1` was null the error should be shown in the code or the app should at least crash when I run it. And it still wouldn´t explain why removing the button from the feature would make it work